# How to print all rows of a pandas dataframe in the pycharm console?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

An attempt to print 100 rows of a pandas dataframe in the console (i.e. `output.iloc[20:120]`) returns something like this where there are dots instead of data

[image]

How can I print the all of the data (no dots)?

My goal is to be able to visually inspect the data, so if you have other suggestions please make them. My current workaround is to write a csv and inspect in excel (which, needless to say, is slow and cumbersome)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. In terms of convenience, calling `with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    print(output.iloc[20:120])` is a little better than writing to csv and opening in excel, but not that much of an improvement if we're honest. Is there a way to set the option so that it doesn't have to be called every time I want to print something in full to the console?

Comment: Running this will work: `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`